# Docker Compose file results in Database connection error

Tags: docker-compose

WordPress file is not connecting with the Database. I don't know what I am doing wrong with my docker compose file. The result of the Docker compose file is also attached to my question. Please I need some help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWpmt.png)

Comment: [edit] your question to post code as text, not image. You can leave the image as supporting content if it contains any useful extra info. This will raise your chance of getting answers.